# goto function with sapper-noscroll

Tags: scroll, sapper, svelte-3

The `goto()` function scrolls to the top of page. Even if its the same page. This was the same behavior with `<a>` tags which was resolved using `sapper-noscroll` thing/feature. Anyway to do the same with `goto()` function?

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with following hack to implement `sapper-noscroll` with `goto()` function:

```js
const myGoto = function() {
    g.href = `/your/link/here`
    g.click()
  }

<a href="/" bind:this={g} hidden class="hidden" sapper-noscroll>a</a>
```